# Python 2.7 Tkinter and ftplib

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.7, ftplib

I have quick question, and it may sound dumb. But for the love of me I can't find a solution online or by myself! I am trying to make a FTP client using python for my self, and I am trying to make a listbox in Tkinter display all the filenames on the FTP server. But I can't get the text to display! Here is the code I have so far below:

```
# Import the FTP object from ftplib
from ftplib import FTP
from Tkinter import *

app = Tk()
app.title("FTP")
app.geometry("300x500")

def handleDownload(block):
    file.write(block)
    print ".",

def login():
    ftp.login(username.get(),password.get())

    # This is where I am held up I tried ftp.retrlines('LIST') but it would
    # not be inserted into to the list box instead it inserted "Tranfer Complete" at the    end!
    # Any suggetion?
    h = ?
    stuff = Listbox(app)
    stuff.insert(END, h)
    stuff.pack()

    filename = "Steam Engine Poster.pdf"

    Label(app, text ='Opening local file ' + filename).pack()
    file = open(filename, 'wb')

    Label(app, text = "Downloading Steam Engine Poster.pdf").pack()

    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, handleDownload)

    Label(app, text = "Closing FTP connection!").pack()

    ftp.close()



ftp = FTP('sciphigames.com')
Label(app, text = "Login").pack()

username = StringVar(None)
username = Entry(app, text = "Username: ")
username.pack()

password = StringVar(None)
password = Entry(app, text = "Password: ")
password.pack()

button = Button(app, text = "Login!", command = login)
button.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get "Transfer Complete" because `retrlines` returns the response code, not *the listing*. If you check the documentation, you'll see that apart from the command, there's a second argument, a callback, that will be called for each line returned. By default it just prints the line to the standard output.

```
lines = []
def append_line(line):
    lines.append(line)
ftp.retrlines('LIST', append_line)
```

Comment: Would you happen to know what that call back would be?

Comment: I've added a little code explaining how to do that. You could make it a little more compact: `ftp.retrlines('LIST', lines.append)`

Comment: Note: with the example code, after `ftp.retrlines` returns, `lines` contains a list where each element is one of the lines replied by the FTP server. Now, it's up to you to process them :)

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and it worked just one last question how do you insert a "\n" for every "," in the list

Comment: You want to join all the lines in one? Eg: `h = '\n'.join(lines)`